# Masquerading traffic with non-default routing table

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, nftables

I have a network set up as follows:

```
                     ┌──────┬────────┐ ┌───────────┐
                     │      │ eno1.1 │ │ Network A │
                     │      │        ├─┤           │
 ┌────────┐ ┌────────┤      │10.0.1.2│ │10.0.1.0/24│
 │ Client │ │  eno2  │      ├────────┘ └───────────┘
 │        ├─┤        │Router│         
 │10.0.0.2│ │10.0 0.1│      ├────────┐ ┌───────────┐
 └────────┘ └────────┤      │ eno1.2 │ │ Network B │
                     │      │        ├─┤           │
                     │      │10.0.2.2│ │10.0.2.0/24│
                     └──────┴────────┘ └───────────┘
```

And I am trying to configure the router to do the following:

1. Route all traffic from `eno2` through `eno1.2`, masquerading it behind `10.0.2.2`
2. Route all other traffic (e.g. from the router itself) through `eno1.1`

I can get traffic from `eno2` to route through `eno1.1` (the router's default gateway) by enabling IP forwarding and setting up a masquerade rule in nftables:

```
$ sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
$ nft -f - <<EOF
table inet test {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
        iifname "eno2" oifname "eno1.1" masquerade
    }
}
EOF
```

But I can't seem to get it route traffic through `eno1.2`. Here's the initial system routes:

```
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eno1.1 proto dhcp src 10.0.1.2 metric 1024 
10.0.1.0/24 dev eno1.1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.2 metric 1024 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eno1.2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.2 metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
```

I set up a new routing table and masquerading for `eno2` like so:

```
$ echo "100 eno2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
$ ip route add default via 10.0.2.1 dev eno1.2 src 10.0.2.2 table eno2
$ ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev eno2 src 10.0.0.1 table eno2
$ ip rule add iif eno2 lookup eno2
$ nft -f - <<EOF
table inet test {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority filter; policy accept;
        iifname "eno2" oifname "eno1.2" masquerade
    }
}
```

And this seems to get me most of the way there. Pinging the "Network B" router (`10.0.2.1`) from the client works fine, however trying to ping any non-local IP results in the replies being dropped by the router. I can see the packets going out on `eno1.2` (correctly masqueraded) and coming back on `eno1.2`, however they are never forwarded to `eno2`.

I managed to trace this down to the following nftables rule which is automatically added by my OS (NixOS):

```
table inet nixos-fw {
    chain rpfilter {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle + 10; policy drop;
        fib saddr . mark . iif oif exists accept
    }
}
```

This seems to be implementing reverse path filtering, and I'm starting to think the issue might be that it's only checking the default routing table and not `eno2`. The [nftables wiki article about `fib`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Matching_routing_information) just says "queries the routing table" and doesn't mention if it's all routing tables or just the default one (it also doesn't mention how to specify a routing table).

I've tried adding an additional rule to route any packets coming in on `eno1.2` via the `eno2` routing table (`ip rule add iif eno1.2 table eno2`), but this didn't fix it.

What might be wrong here? Is it possible to specify a table for `fib` to use?

Comment: I wonder if you need to relax rp_filter on eno1.2.  Maybe something like "sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eno1.2.rp_filter=0"   I'm not sure of the syntax there when there's a dot in the interface name.  You may need to play with it.

You should be able to check "netstat -s" (or nstat) and look for IPReversePathFilter incrementing.

Comment: I've tried disabling `rp_filter` on all interfaces but sadly it didn't help - it seems like this nftables rule is actually blocking traffic that `rp_filter` allowed through. I've done some testing and it seems like disabling this nftables rule and using the kernel's filtering (set to strict) might be the best option, as that does actually seem to check the correct tables and allows the return traffic to reach eno2. I'll do some more testing and post this as the answer once I'm happy it works properly.

Comment: The nixos-fw rule involves a mark. Is there anywhere else (in `nft list ruleset` and even in `ip rule` in case other rules exist) where a rule uses a mark? If yes, it would be best to provide the whole ruleset and whatever else is related to it.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? I suggested you provide the whole output of `nft list ruleset`  + `ip rule` so the role of the mark can possibly be found.

Comment: My understanding is that the `mark .` is just checking that a matching route exists in the FIB with the same `mark` (it's concatnated with the source address and input interface). None of my other rules use marks. I've got this working now by just disabling this rule and using the kernel's reverse path filtering. I've also tried dropping the `mark` out of the concatenation but that still doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing, the `fib` statement appears to only use the default routing table and does not check any other tables. To fix this issue, I've removed the `rpfilter` chain and have enabled the kernel's reverse path filtering instead.

Comment: I disagree. fib does like `ip route get`, but since you solved your problem, no big deal.